# Android-saripaar,how to identify different widget validation

Tags: android, saripaar

Android-saripaar,how to identify different widget validation
I have two buttons in my class both have different validation, how can I identify that onValidationSucceded() which widget's callback returns

Comment: Can you describe more about the problem you are facing..